# which is the best way to replace microsoft office word contain in java?

Tags: java

i am creating a new word document in the base of reading existing word template.
once i read existing template i replaced some content from it and write that content in a new word document.

i am using POIXMLDocument class of apache POI api for creating a word document.

problem is that when i read a table from existing template and replace some contain in that table and write that table in the new document, Table appears with some unwanted space.

Could you give me some tips how can i copy an exact table from the template in the new document.